# SCNetworkReachabilityRef Leak on xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a leak with that var's and I don't know how solve it...

Here's the code :

```
bool success = false;
    const char *host_name = [@"www.google.com" cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL, host_name);
    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
    success = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachability, &flags);
    bool isAvailable = success && (flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable) && 
    !(flags & kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired);
    if (isAvailable) {
        ...
    }else{
        ...
    }
    CFRelease(reachability);
```

Leaks :
90,5% for the line

```
SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL, host_name);
```

and 9,5% for this line :

```
success = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachability, &flags);
```

That's it. So if you can help me, it could be very nice :D Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You're not actually leaking. Notice how the apparent leak only happens the first time you call into the API? It's just background setup and can be ignored.

However, when working with Core Foundation and compatible types, you *must* check for `NULL` return values. If you pass `NULL` to `CFRelease()`, your app will crash. So you *must* do this:

```
bool success = false;
const char *host_name = [@"www.google.com" cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL, host_name);
if (reachability) {
    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
    success = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachability, &flags);
    bool isAvailable = success && (flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable) && 
    !(flags & kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired);
    if (isAvailable) {
        ...
    }else{
        ...
    }
    CFRelease(reachability);
}
```

Note the added `if` statement.